# How to GD Library on Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i install on google cloud run

```
FROM composer:2.1.6 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install

FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=build /app /var/www/
COPY docker/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY .env.example /var/www/.env
RUN chmod 777 -R /var/www/storage/ && \
    echo "Listen 8080" >> /etc/apache2/ports.conf && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/ && \
    a2enmod rewrite
```

The code above works.
but i try add GD Library

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo pdo_mysql
```

show error failed: step exited with non-zero status: 127

```
Step #0: Step 12/12 : RUN chmod 777 -R /var/www/storage/ &&     echo "Listen 8080" >> /etc/apache2/ports.conf &&     chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/ &&     a2enmod rewrite
Step #0:  ---> Running in 089bcc7fdaac    
Step #0: /bin/sh: a2enmod: not found
    Step #0: The command '/bin/sh -c chmod 777 -R /var/www/storage/ &&     echo "Listen 8080" >> /etc/apache2/ports.conf &&     chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/ &&     a2enmod rewrite' returned a non-zero code: 127
    Finished Step #0
    ERROR
    ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 127
```

Comment: The problem here is not related to GD Library but because **a2enmod** is missing, is there any reason to switch from **php:7.3-apache-stretch** to **php:7.4-fpm**

Comment: i change to php:7.4-apache that work